# replace tag name on xml or html with python

Tags: python, html, xml

i'd like to change some html tag name.
let me know the method with python code.:

**As-is**

```
<div class="title-title-1">hello</div>
<div class="text-body">i like you</div>
<div class="p">hehe</div>
```

**To be**

```
<title-title-1>hello</title-title-1>
<text-body>i like you</text-body>
<p>hehe</p>
```

somebody help me!!

Comment: Try using beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)**

**Demo:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<div class="title-title-1">hello</div>
<div class="text-body">i like you</div>
<div class="p">hehe</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")

title = soup.find("div", class_="title-title-1").text
body = soup.find("div", class_="text-body").text
p = soup.find("div", class_="p").text

toFrame = """<title-title-1>{0}</title-title-1>
<text-body>{1}</text-body>
<p>{2}</p>""".format(title, body, p)

print(toFrame)
```

**Output:**

```
<title-title-1>hello</title-title-1>
<text-body>i like you</text-body>
<p>hehe</p>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. you save me ^^